# C++ boost::asio::async_write send problems

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

When I call `async_write()`, the remote peer is not receiving data until I call `async_write()` again.  For example, I have 3 packets, `a`, `b`, and `c`:

```
SendPacket(a); // the remote side receives nothing
SendPacket(b); // the remote side receives packet a
SendPacket(c); // the remote side receives packet b
```

This is my code for sending:

```
void Session::SendPacket(packet p)
{
    dword len = p.Lenght(); 
    byte* buffer_send = new byte[len + 4]; //4 cause of the header

    memcpy(buffer_send + 4, p.GetRaw(), len); // copy everything to the buffer +4, 0-4 is header

    m_codec.EncodePacket(buffer_send, len);

    boost::asio::async_write(m_socket, boost::asio::buffer(buffer_send, len + 4),
                boost::bind(&Session::OnPacketSend, this, len + 4, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred, buffer_send));

}

void Session::OnPacketSend(int len, const boost::system::error_code &e, size_t bytes_transferred, byte* buf)
{
    // this asynchronously fires when packet data is sent
    delete[] buf;
    if (e || bytes_transferred != len)
    {
        Stop();
        return;
    }
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
packet pp;

pp.WriteWord(0);
pp.WriteDword(4);
pp.WriteWord(0);

SendPacket(pp);
```

Also, when `SendPacket()` accepts `packet` by value instead of reference, a crash occurs.

Gr

Comment: Do you have another thread servicing the io service? Otherwise, the composed functions will have to wait. How do you protect the socket from conflicting accesses? I don't see you using a strand. (It seems like you're expecting the operation to be completed "somehow" without actually having any code to complete it.)

Comment: Every socket uses 1 io_service, which I get from a pool, like this: http://pastebin.com/F4TSSEBA . So every session is inside 1 thread.

Comment: Then there's no way the socket can make any forward progress while the thread is doing anything else. Also, you can't call `async_write` until the previous `async_write` completes -- otherwise the two operations can interleave.

Comment: Why would the thread do something else? The problem is not there, it really is so that the first packet is send, when I want to send the second one.

Comment: What is this thread doing when the send isn't happening? Because you need to allow the thread to finish the pending asynchronous operations. Also, you must not start a second operation until the first one completes (or they will interleave unpredictably). If you post a self-contained, compilable, minimal example that demonstrates the problem, I'll show you the specific places where the fixes need to go.

Comment: I think the socket is simply buffering. Also, if copying SendPacket leads to undefined behaviour, you might not have implemented Rule-Of-Three correctly for this type?

Answer (score 2):

When small amounts of data are being written to a socket, such as in the original code (12 bytes~), one typically observes the behavior of data not being sent until subsequent data is written to the socket because of [Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm).  In short, many systems will attempt to mitigate IP/TCP congestion by concatenating small outbound messages into a single message that is then sent.  To explicitly disable this behavior on a per-socket basis, set the [`boost::asio::ip::tcp::no_delay`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/no_delay.html) option:

```cpp
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
// ...
boost::asio::ip::tcp::no_delay option(true);
socket.set_option(option);
```

With sufficient bandwidth, disabling Nagle may result in higher throughput.  Yet, it still may be worth examining the application protocol and logic much more to determine when or what data may be buffered, and when it needs to be immediately sent.